# Watermark dont work after upload picture and set opacity

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a problem, the watermark dont work. I added the options on design -> watermark, uploaded images, set opacity and size, but the watermark dont show on the picture.

What can i do ?

Magento version 1.7.0.2

Comment: Have you cleared your images cache?

Comment: first thing i done :)

Comment: Have you solved the problem?